# How can i get keys of SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS?

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I'm using django1.9 with python-social-auth.

And I want to implement a user's login with Facebook account.
Then I want to get information like their gender / age / location / job etc..

How can I get key names which I should set to SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS ?

thanks

Comment: Please show us some code to see what you've tried so. Please see [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on "How do I ask a good question?".

Comment: I'm so sorry. I've set fields like this

SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
        'fields': 'id,name,email,picture',
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the field list:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/

I use some of them:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id,name,email,gender,about,birthday,first_name,hometown', 
}
```